# Removing subviews error: Thread 5: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1

Tags: ios, swift3

I have created a method in my ViewController class to remove all the subviews:

```
public func removeSubViews() {
        for subview in self.view.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

However my subview takes up the entire screen so I placed a button on the subview that calls this func:

```
@IBAction func x(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let mainView = ViewController()
        mainView.removeSubViews()
    }
```

However when this button is pressed I get an error:

> Thread 5: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x1003dc750)

What does this mean? Is there a better way to remove the subviews?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are allocating a `ViewController` class to `mainView` which is a new instance of the `ViewController` class. Use the already allocated instance ie, `self`.  Just use

`self.removeSubViews()`

instead of `mainView.removeSubViews()`

Comment: Also, I moved the method the the subView's ViewController class.